# as.list method that works with Reduce

Tags: r, functional-programming, r-s4

I have created a custom S4 class that maintains a list of objects. I want to be able to use `Reduce` on the list contained within this S4 class however when I implement the `as.list` method the function does not dispatch properly from within `Reduce`. Here is a simple reprex:

```
myClass <- setClass("myClass", slots=c(data="list"))

setMethod("as.list", "myClass", function(x, ...) x@data)

items <- myClass(data=list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

> Reduce(`+`, items@data)
[1] 15 

> Reduce(`+`, as.list(items))
[1] 15

> Reduce(`+`, items) ## fails
Error in as.list.default(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

**How can I direct R to dispatch on my custom class when calling `as.list` from within `Reduce`?**

`as.list` is used in the body of `Reduce` and it even has visibility to my method however it falls back on `as.list.default` and doesn't dispatch properly.

```
> Reduce
function (f, x, init, right = FALSE, accumulate = FALSE) 
{
    mis <- missing(init)
    len <- length(x)
    if (len == 0L) 
        return(if (mis) NULL else init)
    f <- match.fun(f)
    if (!is.vector(x) || is.object(x)) 
        x <- as.list(x)
...
```

Edited to add version info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7600)
```

Comment: Look at the last example in `?setOldClass`

Comment: The docs suggest I add a call to `setOldClass` immediately after my class definition. However, this does not solve my problem. Further, the use of `prototype` used in the docs is not recommended ... according to the docs for `prototype`.

Comment: it looks like dispactch is happening according to the S3 rules rather than the S4 ones. As well as the call to `setOldClass`, define a function `as.list.myClass` to be equal to your method and see if that works.